# border height 50 % in my div height using css how?

Tags: html, css

**Notes:** I tried all questions & answers related this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but no the success. So please read my question thoroughly.

I want to left border height set `50%` to compare to my div height.

**i want to like this**

[image]

**Below I try  to code**

```css
.sing-wrapper {
    border-left: 3px solid #999; 
    border-bottom: 3px solid #999;
    height:10%;
    width:220px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
}
.cmpny-label
{
 display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="sing-wrapper">
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">

Hello Friends Sign  <br>
Hello Friends Sign  <br>
Hello Friends Sign  <br>
Hello Friends Sign  <br>
Hello Friends Sign  <br>

</div>
<div class="cmpny-label">
 <i style="color:#ccc;"> Signed With my Company
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have something like below approach. adding a pseudo element with a white background

```
.sing-wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  width: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  top: 0; 
  background-color: white;
}
```

```css
.sing-wrapper {
    border-left: 3px solid #999; 
    border-bottom: 3px solid #999;
    height:10%;
    width:220px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
}

.sing-wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  width: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  top: 0; 
  background-color: white;
}

.cmpny-label{
   display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="sing-wrapper">
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">

Hello Friends Sign  <br>
Hello Friends Sign  <br>
Hello Friends Sign  <br>
Hello Friends Sign  <br>
Hello Friends Sign  <br>

</div>
<div class="cmpny-label">
 <i style="color:#ccc;"> Signed With my Company
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much..great answer @dwij